# Data Binding layout strange build error

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project I have Android Data Binding Library v.2.3.3

After adding new aar library dependency I am getting error while compiling project with message

```
/Users/.../app/build/intermediates/data-binding-layout- 
out/.../debug/layout/..-activity.xml:90: error: Error: No resource found 
that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value 
'@id/buttonLayout').
```

I've checked the xml in build/intermediates and it seems quite OK:

```
    ...
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonLayout">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_button_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>   
...
```

What may cause the problem? Is it related to databinding?
I've tried to use the aar library other project and it was working

Comment: Post you whole xml code.

Comment: It is related to your layout problem. Can you share with us your layout xml that has the problem?

Comment: not able to share whole xml, but I think you are right, xml is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mainLayout` you are referencing an ID `@id/buttonLayout` that has not been added to the resources yet as it is declared in the second `RelativeLayout` further down. To solve this you need to add it first with `@+id` like this:

```
...
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_button_size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@id/buttonLayout">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>   
...
```